# How to remove the space between bar and legend in a sapui5 StackedBarChart

Tags: sapui5, stacked-chart

I like to create a barchart and have gotten pretty far.

My chart is a standalone view and next to some other views inside of a Shell>App>Page

View.view.xml:

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="my.controller.Chart"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls"
    xmlns:vizData="sap.viz.ui5.data"
    xmlns:vizFeeds="sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds"
    displayBlock="true"
    height="100%"
    busyIndicatorDelay="0"
    class="myChartView"
>
    <Panel
        headerText="Chart"
        class="sapUiResponsiveMargin"
        width="auto"
    >
        <viz:VizFrame
            vizType="100_stacked_bar"
            id="idDualStackedChart"
            width="100%"
            class="myStackedBarChart"
            vizProperties="{plotArea: {
                                dataLabel:{
                                    visible: true
                                },
                                colorPalette: ['#009c00','#ff0000'],
                                gridline: {
                                    visible: false
                                }
                            },
                            interaction: {
                                noninteractiveMode: true
                            },
                            title:{ visible: false, text:'Auslastung'},
                            categoryAxis: {visible: false},
                            valueAxis: {visible: false},
                            legendGroup: {
                                layout: {
                                    position: 'bottom',
                                    alignment: 'center'
                                }
                            }
                        }"
        >
            <viz:dataset>
                <vizData:FlattenedDataset data="{/items}">
                    <vizData:dimensions>
                        <vizData:DimensionDefinition
                            name="Maschine"
                            value="{Machine}"
                        />
                    </vizData:dimensions>
                    <vizData:measures>
                        <vizData:MeasureDefinition
                            name="Stopped"
                            value="{Stopped}"
                        />
                        <vizData:MeasureDefinition
                            name="Running"
                            value="{Running}"
                        />
                    </vizData:measures>
                </vizData:FlattenedDataset>
            </viz:dataset>
            <viz:feeds>
                <vizFeeds:FeedItem
                    uid="valueAxis"
                    type="Measure"
                    values="Running,Stopped"
                />
                <vizFeeds:FeedItem
                    uid="categoryAxis"
                    type="Dimension"
                    values="Maschine"
                />
            </viz:feeds>
        </viz:VizFrame>
    </Panel>
</mvc:View>
```

Chart.controller.ts

```
import Controller from "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller";
import JSONModel from "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel";

export default class ChartController extends Controller {
  onInit() {
    const oSampleData = new JSONModel("model/Data.json");
    this.getView().setModel(oSampleData);

    const chartFrame = this.byId("idDualStackedChart");
    console.log(chartFrame);
  }
}
```

Data.json

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "Machine": "Q1",
            "Stopped": "20",
            "Running": "40"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Result]

The only problem I have is: There is a lot of space above the chart and a lot of space between the chart-bar and the legend.
How can I decrease/remove this space?